# iTunes ID3 Metadata Vs. Library-only Metadata

Tags: itunes, mp3, id3

What metadata does iTunes store in the song ID3 tags and what will it only store in the library file?  Are the any reference documents that explain this?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes stores the following meta data only in its library file (independent from track files): ratings, play count, artwork. In addition, as far as I know for non mp3 files this list includes album and artist name.

Correct me if I am wrong, but For *.mp3 files album/artist name and track name (even if changed in iTunes) are stored within the track file itself.

You might be interested in this article:

http://www.darcynorman.net/2004/01/25/itunes-metadata-lost/